# How to give read-only access to Azure application insight logs to a user?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-role-environment

I have a problem with permissions and roles. I need to give read-only access to **all** logs in my infrastructure to a user.
My infrastructure is done by different Management groups:

[image]

I am working at `Techical area management group` level... it is like i am working at root level.

Initially, the user had the `Reader` role. Now I have given him a lot of `*** reader` roles. At the end I have given him also some `contributor` role. But no success:

[image]

Now, when he tries to open some log I receive this error:
[image]

> The client '*******' with object id '******' does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.web/sites/config/list/action' over scope '/subscriptions/******/resourcegroups/******-rg-westeu/providers/microsoft.web/sites/******-func-westeu/config/appSettings' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

The error is about listing appSettings.

Well, honestly I do not understand why he need that kind of permission. However, which is the minimum role I can give him for that permission? Does a way exist to know hich role has some permissions?

Thank you

Comment: Contributor role is enough to read the traces.

Comment: I have a Contributor role and I can check any AppInsights Resurce traces.

Comment: Make sure you re checking in the same subscription.

Comment: Yes it is the same subscription. i didn't give him the `Contributor` role and I do not want to give him that role. It is too much. I gave him `Monitor contributor` and `log analytics contributor`.. but the are not enough even if I consider that too much...

Comment: Once try [Application Insights Component Contributor](https://i.imgur.com/0kZRTxn.png), It has the option to Read the [Transaction](https://i.imgur.com/WQu7Dy3.png)

Comment: In the Subscription level try `Application Insights Snapshot Debugger` role.

Comment: If you have permission create your own [custom role](https://i.imgur.com/aupgLYu.png).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitor), `Application Insights Component Contributor` role has an option to `Read Transactions`.

You can check the same in `Roles` => `Application Insights Component Contributor`

[image]

- Create a new custom role with the action `Microsoft.Insights/transactions/read`  and assign this custom role to the user.
- Make sure you have `owner` or `User access Admin` role to create a custom role.
- Here Iam creating the custom role on `Resource Group level`.

Navigate to your `Resource  Group` =>
`Access control (IAM)` => click on `Add` => `Add custom role`.

[image]

- Select clone a role and search for `Application Insights Component Contributor` role => `Review + create`.

[image]

- Now assign this role to the users whom you want to give read access.

Refer this [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) for more info.